# M1 brute force protection, password complexity

Tags: security, password, apple-silicon

What protection does the M1 SoC have against an attacker attempting to brute force the login password of a macOS user?

What password complexity should be enough to stop an attacker from brute forcing a user's login on a M1/Pro/Max-based device?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The main protection against brute-force is that the disk encryption key, that is supposed to be unlocked by the user's password, is [stored within the M1 SoC](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/deployment/dep82064ec40/web) in an Secure Enclave - instead of being stored by disk. This means that you cannot remove the disk from the computer and start brute-forcing the password - instead you would have to brute-force the key, which is many orders of magnitudes harder.

Note that the disk is encrypted and the key stored in the Secure Enclave [no matter if File Vault is turned on or off](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/security/sec4c6dc1b6e/web).

The above mentioned functionality makes it possible for the M1 SoC to enforce even stronger protections against brute forcing the password. It does so by [imposing delays](https://www.apple.com/mideast/mac/docs/Apple_T2_Security_Chip_Overview.pdf) when incorrect passwords have been attempted during the first login after a boot. The delays are according to the following scheme:

| Attempts | Delay (minutes) |
| --- | --- |
| 1-14 | 0 |
| 15-17 | 1 |
| 18-20 | 5 |
| 21-26 | 15 |
| 27-30 | 60 |

When the 30 attempts have been used, it is no longer possible to keep guessing during that login session. A reboot will not help.

The user can boot into the macOS Recovery mode where another 10 attempts are possible. If the user has one or more FileVault recovery mechanisms enabled (i.e. iCloud recovery, a recovery key or an instituational key), it is possible to try 30 times extra for each of the enabled mechanisms - up to a maximum of 90 attempts.

Once those 90 attempts are used, the disk is essentially no longer accessible. The only way forward is to wipe the disk and start over with a fresh installation of macOS.

Should an attacker somehow be able to bypass these delays, there's an additional protection from brute-forcing built in simply by the system being intentionally designed so that generating the key from the password (and thus checking if the password is correct) takes a long while (in terms of CPU time). That means that checking a password takes on the order of 80 ms. That does not sound like a lot, but it means that you can test only 12.5 passwords per second, where as a system with a simple password hash stored on disk might allow for testing millions of passwords per second.

In regards to your second question, this means that in order to protect yourself against brute-forcing, your password really do not have to be that complex. 90 attempts will get you nowhere if you're trying to brute-force a 4 character password of mixed upper/lower case letters and numbers.

However, I do recommend using more complex passwords, as there are other threats than simply brute-forcing. For example, someone could be looking over your shoulder, and in that case a very simple password would be easier to recognize and memorize.

If we assume that we're dealing with a hacker that has somehow found a way to circumvent the delays imposed by the M1 chip, and we want to keep our account secured for 100 years - a simple calculation would be something like:

```
12.5 combinations/sec * 100 years = 12.5 c/s * 3.155.760.000 s ~ 40 * 10^9 combinations
```

This means that on average an attacker would use 100 years to brute-force a password of up to 80 * 10^9 combinations.

If we assume your password is built of a mix of characters coming from the set of 26 lower-case letters, 26 upper-case letters, 10 numeric digits and 10 special characters - you would find that a password of at least 6 characters would have more than enough complexity (i.e. `72^6 ~ 139 * 10^9`).

Note that the above calculations are a simplified way of looking at the problem. For example, in practice your M1 Mac would probably not survive 100 years of 24/7 operation!

Comment: Exactly the facts I was looking for. Thank you so much for going to every aspect of the Q!

Comment: "The only way forward is to wipe the disk and start over with a fresh installation of macOS": could you provide a link detailing that piece? I'm [trying to protect](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/436445/how-to-make-m1-macbook-pro-2021-useless-if-lost-stolen) against exactly that: for recovery key-based FileVault, the key risk in case of theft is "Macbook can be fully erased / reinstalled" which itself requires admin password. Do your findings actually mean that a thief can wipe Macbook after simply trying 100-200 guesses to admin password?

Comment: @yurkennis The link is already in my answer. I'm a bit puzzled as to why you think erasing the MacBook in case of theft is the key risk? - That doesn't make any sense whatsoever to me. Normally you would hope a laptop is erased by a thief (or your own remote wipe).

Comment: I apologize if I missed it: I really tried all the links from the answer, but failed to find any reference to easily wiping the disk without having admin password.

Comment: Look at the linked PDF, page 7, last paragraph. It doesn't say that you can "easily wipe the disk", that's not what I wrote in my answer either. But effectively, it is the same.

Comment: On key risk: my ideal outcome in case of theft is that Macbook can not be usable any more (become a "brick" device), only become a "donor" source of parts (which seriously affects resell value). In the latter case, there's more chance to get it back to me for a "ransom".

Comment: On page 7, I read only "Once those attempts are exhausted, the Secure Enclave will no longer process any requests to decrypt the volume or verify the password". But how we can imply that the attacker becomes able to completely wipe Macbook at this point? Again, I apologize if I miss something here.

Comment: You're the one implying that the attacker becomes able to completely wipe the MacBook. I haven't written that, Apple hasn't written that - you did. However, as I wrote earlier the only way forward is to wipe the disk. What use would the data on there be if they can't be decrypted?

Comment: BTW: You write that the answer was exactly what you were looking for - could you then accept the answer?

Comment: From what I found (and tried), on M1/Monterey there's no normally way to erase Mac without providing MacOS admin credentials, neither [via MacOS Recovery boot](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/mac-help/mchl82829c17/12.0/mac/12.0#:~:text=then%20click%20Next.-,Select%20an%20administrator%20account%2C%20then%20click%20Next.,Enter%20the%20password%20for%20the%20administrator%20account,-%2C%20then%20click%20Continue) nor via [System Preferences > "Erase All Contents and Settings"](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT212749#:~:text=administrator%20credentials). That's why I'm asking.

Comment: Just accepted the answer, I always forget to do that timely.

Comment: I think this is just a question of semantics. When you say that you're concerned about "wiping the disk" what you actually mean is that you're concerned about a thief being able to reinstall macOS and reuse the computer. When you throw away any chance of decrypting the data, you have effectively wiped the disk (this is the method used to wipe disks actually).

Comment: Then do you mind if we remove this piece "The only way forward is to wipe the disk and start over with a fresh installation of macOS." from the answer altogether? Unless you are aware of any way to actually start over with a fresh installation without having admin password.

Comment: I don't want to remove that piece. As a user, if you have entered the wrong password 90 times, your only way forward is to wipe the disk and start over. You can do that without knowing the admin password.

Comment: "You can do that without knowing the admin password" Can you? How?

Comment: You can boot into Recovery mode and click that you have forgotten your admin user's login password and then authenticate via iCloud instead - and reinstall macOS. The other option is booting the Mac into DFU mode and restoring it with the Apple Configurator 2 tool.

Comment: Thank you--those two ways are worth researching!

Comment: @jksoegaard, I have a question· does this also apply to Intel Macs with the T2 Security Chip ?.

Comment: @George Yes, it does!

Comment: I believe there is some issue with this protection as I just locked myself from my M1 Pro MacBook. I powered on my Mac as usual and started to type incorrect password. By the time I realised that I'm typing incorrect password (after I dunno 2-3 attempts) I noticed there is a message saying I have to wait 1 minute.
After waiting one minute and typing this time the correct password I got locked out for another 5 minutes. Thus, I waited and typed the correct password again. Yet… now I can't log in. Mac is not even asking to help with password and there is no timer. WTF!?

Comment: What do you mean by "typed the correct password" and "now I can't login"? - What happens exactly? - It sounds like you have forgotten the password, and are denied entry. Alternatively you could have CAPS LOCK enabled or a broken key on your keyboard, which makes the computer register a different password than what you intend to enter.