# Which user(s) can activate erased Mac with their device password after Mark As Lost?

Tags: activation-lock, find-my-mac

I have the following 3 users on my M1 Macbook Air 2020:

- userA: admin created during macOS installation, no AppleID connected
- userB: non-admin, its own AppleID connected, FindMy disabled
- userC: non-admin, its own AppleID connected, FindMy enabled

---

After I invoke `Mark As Lost` in `Find My` iPhone app logged in with UserB's AppleID and rebooting into Activate Mac, I can `Erase Mac` without providing any user credentials. After Mac is erased, I need to activate it:

- either by providing AppleID and password
- OR via `Use Device Password` option

---

Now the question is:

**Which of UserA, UserB, UserC device passwords should be accepted for "Use Device Password"?**

---

**Some further details of my setup:**

UserC's AppleID is an adult, non-guardian member of family owned by UserB.

FileVault enabled during initial MacOS setup; encryption key not associated with any AppleID. Password reset using AppleID is disabled for all users.

---

**My own experiments** gave inconsistent results:

- after Mac was locked when UserC logged in, I managed to activate it with UserC's *device* password
- after Mac was locked when UserB logged in, I failed to activate it with *any of* UserA, UserB, UserC *device* passwords: error messages varied between:

  - `Activation lock server cannot be reached`
  - `The password for this Mac can no longer be used to remove Activation Lock. The password was entered incorrectly too many times`

Each experiment takes a couple of hours, so I hope there's official docs / third-party research on the topic.

Comment: Out of interest - is this work you're doing for a hobby, as a work assigment for an employer, or working for the government/state?

Comment: @jksoegaard Just a minor episode of my earlier [meta-question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/436445/how-to-make-m1-macbook-pro-2021-useless-if-lost-stolen). Macs are my personal ones, not provided by employer.

Comment: Yes, I see the link to earlier questions! I was wondering as this is something that takes hours and hours to work out and document - seems to be quite a big task for personal usage, so I assumed you were doing this for work.

Answer (score 1):

From [Apple Platform Security](https://support.apple.com/guide/security/activation-lock-security-sec0f8dfd030/1/web/1#sec3d66198a1), it *looks like* only the **userC** *(non-admin, its own AppleID connected, FindMy enabled)* can unlock the Mac, *assuming that* his device password is a replacement for iCloud credentials:

> If the device is Activation Locked, recoveryOS prompts the user for iCloud credentials **of the user that enabled Activation Lock** at this time.

BUT it is not said explicitly, so I may be wrong--so I welcome input from you guys.

---

One more thought: it looks like Macs report user's (encrypted) device password to Apple servers for accounts connected to AppleID. One of such examples is when you are asked on one device to provide that user's local password on other device, as a extra mile to ensure that AppleID is used by the same person across devices.

This gives one more reason to think that the password should work only for accounts having AppleID associated with them. And together with "recoveryOS prompts the user for iCloud credentials of the user that enabled Activation Lock at this time", it suggests that only the account with activated FindMy should be able to activate with device password.

Still, it's very indirect evidence.